# Image not moving?

Tags: python, pygame

I was making a little game. I have a main menu and there are two buttons, if someone presses the tutorial button the screen is filled Black and a image appears on screen. I wish to move this image yet despite me placing in the keyboard instructions and how much it should move it just doesn't move. The image that isn't moving the hi_image.

```
# Import pygame
import pygame
# Colors
RED = ( 255, 0, 0)
GREEN = ( 0, 255, 0)
BLUE =  (0, 0, 255)
PUPLE = ( 217, 0, 255)
BROWN = ( 105, 84, 62)
YELLOW = ( 255, 255, 0)
ORANGE = ( 255, 115, 0)
BLACK = ( 0, 0, 0)
WHITE = ( 255, 255, 255)
pygame.init()
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
# Screen Dynamics
screen = pygame.display.set_mode([1000,700])
#Title of window
pygame.display.set_caption("Space Victory")

#Variables before main loop
color_white = False
tutorial_white = False
x = 500
speed = (5, 5) # Amount of pixels to move every frame (loop).
moving_up = False
moving_right = False
moving_down = False
moving_left = False 
#Positions of Graphics
background_position = [0,0]
start_position = [100,600]
tutorial_position = [700, 600]
hi_position = [x,x]


#The graphics
background_image = pygame.image.load("spacebackground.png").convert()
start_image = pygame.image.load("start.png").convert()
tutorial_image = pygame.image.load("tutorial.png").convert()
hi_image = pygame.image.load("izzat.png").convert()
hi_image.set_colorkey(BLACK)
position = izzat_image.get_rect()
# Sounds


# Main loop ___________________________________________________________
done = False

while not done:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = True

    #The main menu
            #The buttons and background image
    screen.blit(background_image, background_position)
    screen.blit(start_image, start_position)
    screen.blit(tutorial_image,tutorial_position)

            #If buttons get pressed screen does this.
    mouse_pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    white_rect = pygame.Rect(100,600,177,44)
    tutorial_rect = pygame.Rect(700,600,177,44)
    if pygame.mouse.get_pressed()[0] and white_rect.collidepoint(mouse_pos):
        color_white = True
    if pygame.mouse.get_pressed()[2] and white_rect.collidepoint(mouse_pos):
        color_white = False
    if color_white:
        screen.fill(WHITE)
    if pygame.mouse.get_pressed()[0] and  tutorial_rect.collidepoint(mouse_pos):
        tutorial_white = True
    if pygame.mouse.get_pressed()[2] and tutorial_rect.collidepoint(mouse_pos):
        tutorial_white = False
    if tutorial_white:
        screen.fill(BLACK)
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                    x -= 10
                if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                    x += 10
                if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    x += 10
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                    x -= 10
        screen.blit(hi_image,hi_position)

    #Flip the display    
    pygame.display.flip()
    pygame.time.delay(100)
    clock.tick(60)
#Quitting the game
pygame.quit()
```

Comment: Shouldn't you be using [sprites](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html)?

Comment: Wouldn't I have the same problem if I used sprites.

Comment: Im reporting you ppperry for voting down every single question I had for no reason.

Comment: Huh? I did not even vote down this question. Even if I did, how would you know? Votes are anonymous.

Comment: The time period of your posts matched the person who downvoted everything.

Answer (score 0):

you are not updating the menu position, just x.  you need to update the actual menu position

```
    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
        if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
            hi_position[1] -= 10
        if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
            hi_position[1] += 10
        if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
            hi_position[0] += 10
        if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
            hi_position[0] -= 10
```

Comment: OK, you are getting the events twice, after the first event.get there are no events in the queue.  Remove the event.get line in this part and try again: ` if tutorial_white:
        screen.fill(BLACK)
        for event in pygame.event.get():`